# selected splitted value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns A, B in oracle where A value has values like that xx-target-xx
xx any data but target is exists

```
A 
--------
xx-target-xx
xx-target
```

i neet to return only 'target' from text
i tired this

```
select TRIM(substr(A, 0, instr(A, '-') - 1))  from mytable
```

but the result returns `xx` not `target`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR`. You want the second string of any characters except the minus sign:

```
select a, regexp_substr(a, '[^-]+', 1, 2) from mytable;
```

Using `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` instead is a tad more complicated, but possible of course:

```
select a, substr(a,
                 instr(a, '-') + 1,
                 instr(a || '-', '-', 1, 2) - instr(a, '-') - 1
                ) as value
from mytable;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e75b878bbd6300e9207cd698bb3029ec